# Foreign key same table laravel get tree view

Tags: php, laravel, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I'm working with a Laravel 5.5 project .

I have `locations` table with the following definition:

```
$table->increments('id');
$table->string('location_name',50);
$table->integer('location_id')->unsigned();
$table->foreign('location_id')->references('id')->on('locations');          
$table->softDeletes();
$table->timestamps();
```

now the primary key and the forgen key at same table 
id and location id 
and id have this relation in location model

```
public function get_sub()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Location','location_id','id');
}
public function get_father()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Location','location_id','id');
}
```

now i need to draw ul li tree view to start with location_id is null 
i did this

```
@foreach($locations->where('location_id','=','null') as $location)

@endforeach
```

this loop start the first parent location 
what i am need is while loop or for loop to nest all children locations inside the first foreach loop and nest the grandchildren inside the children loop as ul li or anything else like this photo
[image]

thanks

Comment: Show us the code you have so far :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this just a little confusing but very easy to load nth level tree in relation. For this we can create a recursive function to load child or parent relation.

```
// Location model
// loads only 1st level children
public function children()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Location::class, 'parent_id', 'id');
}

// recursive, loads all children
public function childrenRecursive()
{
   return $this->children()->with('childrenRecursive');
}

// load 1st level parent
public function parent()
{
   return $this->belongsTo(Location::class,'parent_id', 'id');
}

// recursive load all parents.
public function parentRecursive()
{
   return $this->parent()->with('parentRecursive');
}

// here is how you can load the target tree structure.
$locations = Location::with('childrenRecursive')->whereNull('parent_id')->get();


//here is how you can create your menu tree.
function createMenuTree($locations) {
    echo "<ul>";
    foreach ($locations as $location) {

        if ($location->children->isEmpty() !== false) {
            echo "<li>" . $location->name;
            menu($location->children);
            echo "</li>";
        } else {
            echo "<li>" . $location->name . "</li>";
        }
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: (`id`, `location_name`, `location_id`)
(1, 'المستودع الرئيسي', NULL),
(2, 'مستودع فوتينا', 1),
(9, 'سدة يمين', 2),
(10, 'معرض الاوتوستراد', 1),
(11, 'سدة شمال', 2),
(12, 'رف 51', 9),
(13, 'sdaasf', NULL); i need to draw nested ul li from this values

Comment: you can create a function and call it recursively to create some html and echo it out .

Comment: menu($location->children) should be 
createMenuTree($location->children);